# Quotient in LOOP program

Tags: turing-machines, computability, loops, primitive-recursion

I want to construct a LOOP-computable program for the integer division (quotient):

x = a DIV b

The LOOP specification can be seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOOP_(programming_language)

I don't know how to do this without a while.

Comment: Hint, you have to use [if-then-else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOOP_(programming_language)#If_then_else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to implement the following algorithm:

```
result = 0
while a >= 0:
  a = a - b
  result = result + 1
end while
return result - 1
```

As you mention, there is no `while`. However, since we have an a priori upper bound on the number of rounds, we can simulate the `while` as follows:

```
result = 0
repeat a + 1 times:
  if a >= 0:
    a = a - b
    result = result + 1
  end if
end repeat
return result - 1
```

It remains to implement the conditional and subtraction. In fact, you can't really implement the conditional, since all numbers are automatically non-negative. However, this is easy to fix by replacing the condition `a >= 0` with the condition `a > 0`. I'll let you work out the minor changes required to implement this change.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the unique integer $x$ such that $b x \le a$ and $b(x+1) > a$. With this approach, you don't need a WHILE statement.